# Should the STM32 HAL be included as a precompiled library

Tags: compilation, embedded, static-libraries, stm32

I have a Keil STM32 project for a STM32L0. I sometimes (more often than I want) have to change the include paths or global defines. This will trigger a complete recompile for **all** code because it needs to ‘check’ for changed behaviour because of these changes.  The problem is: I didn’t necessarily change relevant parameters for the HAL and as such it isn’t needed (as far as I understand) that these files are completely recompiled. This recompilation takes up quite a bit of time because I included all the HAL drivers for my STM32L0.

Would a good course of action be to create a separate project which compiles the HAL as a single library and include that in my main project? (This would of course be done for every microcontroller separately as they have different HALs).

ps. the question is not necessarily only useful for this specific example but the example gives some scope to the question.

pps. for people who aren't familiar with the STM32 HAL. It is the standardized interface with which the program interfaces with the underlying hardware. It is supplied in `.c` and `.h` files instead of the precompiled form of the STD/STL.

**update**

Here is an example of the defines that need to be managed in my example project:

> `STM32L072xx,USE_B_BOARD,USE_HAL_DRIVER, REGION_EU868,DEBUG,TRACE`

Only `STM32L072xx`, and `DEBUG` are useful for configuring the HAL library and thus there shouldn't be a need for me to recompile the HAL when I change `TRACE` from defined to undefined. Therefore it seems to me that the HAL could be managed separately.

**edit**

Seeing as a close vote has been cast: I've read the [don't ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and my question seeks to constructively add to the knowledge of building STM32 programs and find a best practise on how to more effectively use the HAL libraries. I haven't found any questions on SO about building the HAL as a static library and therefore this question at least qualifies as unique. This question is also meant to invite a rich answer which elaborates on the pros/cons of building the HAL as a separate static library.

Comment: It is a terrible idea. You can create the project for your liking but you will give up very soon.

Comment: @P__J__ Can you elaborate on that answer (which you've put in the comments)? As this is just a statement without references and thus not contributing to the knowledge on stackoverflow.

Comment: As I told you - you can create a project for your liking. IMO it is a wrong idea as HAL drivers depends on emany defines. When you change the project settings it is wise to rebuild the **whole** project. But it is up to you. BTW your question is not about the programming only project organization and it is 100% opinion based - IMO it is OFF TOPIC here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer here is.. it depends. As already pointed out in the comments, it depends on how you're planning to manage your projects. To answer your question in an unbiased way:

Option #1 - having HAL sources directly in your project means rebuilding HAL every time anything in its (and underlying) headers changes, which you've already noticed. Downside of it is longer build times. Upside - you are sure that what you build is what you get.

Option #2 - having HAL as a precompiled static library. Upside - shorter build times, downside - you can no longer be absolutely certain that the HAL library you include actually works as you want it to. In particular, you'd need to make sure in some way that all the `#define`s are exactly the same as when the library has been built. This includes project-wide definitions (`DEBUG`, `STM32L072xx` etc.), as well as anything in HAL config files (`stm32l0xx_hal_conf.h`).

Seeing how you're a Keil user - maybe it's just a matter of enabling multi-core build? See this link: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124201769.htm. HAL library isn't so large that build times should be a concern when it comes to rebuilding its source files.

If I was to express my opinion and experience - personally I wouldn't do it, as it may lead to lower reliability or side effects that will be very hard to diagnose and will only get worse as you add more source files and more libraries like this. Not to mention adding more people to work on the project and explaining to them how they "need to remember to rebuild X library when they change given set of header files or project-wide definitions".

In fact, we've ran into the same dilemma for the code base I work on - it spans over 10k source and header files in total, some of which are configuration-specific and many of which are shared. It's highly modular which allows us to quickly create something new (both hardware- and software-wise) just by configuring existing code, mainly through a set of header files. However because this configuration is done through headers, making a change in them usually means rebuilding a large portion of the project. Even though build times get annoying sometimes, we opted against making static libraries for the reasons mentioned above. To me personally it's better to prioritize reliability, as in "I know what I build".

If I was to give any general tips that help to avoid rebuilds as your project gets large:

- Avoid global headers holding all configuration. It's usually tempting to shove all configuration in one place, create pretty comments and sections for each software module in this one file. It's easier to manage this way (until this file becomes too big), but because this file is so common, it means that any change made to it will cause a full rebuild. Split such files to separate headers corresponding to each module in your project.
- Include header files only where you need them. I sometimes see an approach where there are header files created that only "bundle" other header files and such header file is later included. In this case, making a change to any of those "smaller" headers will have an effect of having to recompile all source files including the larger file. If such file didn't exist, then only sources explicitly including that one small header would have to be recompiled. Obviously there's a line to be drawn here - including too "low level" headers may not be the greatest idea either, e.g. they may not be meant to be included as being internal library files which may change any time.
- Prioritize including headers in source files over header files. If you have a pair of your own `*.c` (`*.cpp`) and `*.h` files - let's say `temp_logger.c/.h` and you need ADC - then unless you really need some ADC definition in your header (which you likely won't), then include the ADC header file in your `temp_logger.c` file. Later on, all files making use of the `temp_logger` functions won't have to be re-compiled in case HAL gets rebuilt again.

Comment: Great answer! I do indeed know about multi core compilation but was just wandering wat more experienced people might say in relation to this 'problem' and what pros and cons are.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is yes, build the HAL into a library.  The benefit of faster build time outweighs the risk of the library getting out of date.  After some point early in the project it's unusual for me to change something that would affect the HAL.  But the faster build time pays off many times.

I create a multi-project workspace with one project for the HAL library, another project for the bootloader, and a third project for the application.  When I'm developing, I only rebuild the application project.  When I make a release build, I select Project->Batch Build and rebuild all three projects.  This way the release builds always use all the latest code and build settings.

Also, on the Options for Target dialog, Output tab, unchecking Browse Information will *greatly* reduce the build time.